# "Error in fitter..." While trying to use lrm function from rms library

Tags: r, linear-regression, rms

I'm trying to run a small data table through the lrm function from the rms library, but every time I run it I get this:

```
Error in fitter(X, Y, offset = offs, penalty.matrix = penalty.matrix,  : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Here's some reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rms)

data <- tribble(
~a, ~b, ~c,
"name", 2, 77.95535,
"name", 2, 81.36152,
"name", 2, 80.87081,
"name", 2, 80.59054,
"name", 2, 79.36807,
"name", 2, 82.42083,
"name", 2, 78.80646,
"name", 2, 78.88949
)

lmod <- lrm(b~c, data, penalty=0, x=T, y=T, tol=1e-10, maxit=1e6)
```

I've tried a variety of things. I tried switching b~c to c~b (I know it wouldn't yield the same data) and I got an error, but not the same error. I tried using only the first two parameters, as well as a variety of including or excluding the following ones. I've also tried debugging and following the code into the lrm function, and I narrowed it down to (shocker) the fitter function.

Here's some resources that I've been using that you might find helpful for yourselves or to help me. If there's anything I forgot to include drop a comment and I'll fill in what I can :) Thanks!

[R Reference Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf)
[lrm Function Description](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/6.0-0/topics/lrm)
[R for Data Science (book)](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)
[lrm Function Source Code](https://rdrr.io/cran/rms/src/R/lrm.s)

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error using your supplied data. Then I changed some `b` to 1, the error disappeared:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
  "name", 2, 77.95535,
  "name", 2, 81.36152,
  "name", 1, 80.87081,
  "name", 1, 80.59054,
  "name", 2, 79.36807,
  "name", 1, 82.42083,
  "name", 1, 78.80646,
  "name", 2, 78.88949
)

lmod <- lrm(b~c, data = data, penalty=0, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tol=1e-14, maxit=1e10)
lmod

Logistic Regression Model

 lrm(formula = b ~ c, data = data, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, penalty = 0, 
     tol = 1e-14, maxit = 1e+10)

                   Model Likelihood    Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test           Indexes          Indexes    
 Obs         8    LR chi2      0.00    R2       0.000    C       0.500    
  1          4    d.f.            1    g        0.000    Dxy     0.000    
  2          4    Pr(> chi2) 1.0000    gr       1.000    gamma   0.000    
 max |deriv| 3                         gp       0.000    tau-a   0.000    
                                       Brier    0.250                     

           Coef   S.E.    Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
 Intercept 0.0000 39.9600 0.00   1.0000  
 c         0.0000  0.4992 0.00   1.0000
```

I know it's only a subset of your data, but maybe all rows in `b` have value 2? You can check that with e.g., `table(data$b)`

Comment: This is actually all the data for that "name", and they are all  2. What does that mean?

Comment: Not sure what causes the error. But logistic regression can run into problems when the classes are perfectly separable, so it maybe an over/underflow in the ML estimation. But it works when fitting the logistic regression with glm: `data$b <- as.factor(data$b)
mylogit <- glm(b ~ c, data = data, family = "binomial")`

Comment: I'm a humble programmer... Can you explain the what the goal of linear regression is, and what the difference is between lrm and glm?